# Why am I consistently getting these 2 errors in my Google Closure code?

Tags: google-closure-library

I am using Plovr to compile my javascript with this config file.

```
// File: config.js
{
  "debug": true,
  "id": "myfirstapp",
  "paths": ".",
  "inputs": "main.js",
  "level": "VERBOSE",
  "mode": "ADVANCED",
  "pretty-print": true
}
```

Strangely, my app works, but I am consistently getting these  2 errors in Chrome Console.

```
GET http://www.myunreleasedapp.com/deps.js 404 (NOT FOUND) a.js:181
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined
```

I examined the second error and discovered that the property `Params.settings` is undefined, so calling `Params.settings.debug` produces this error. However, I am not sure where in my Closure code to resolve either of these two errors. Any advice on what to look out for in my code?

The second error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined`
) oddly occurs on this really long line in 58852.user.js:

```
saveSettings();Extend(that,Params);Params.enabled=
(Registry.getKey("enabled","enabled")=="enabled"?true:false);Params.isPage=
(getFromId("jewelFansTitle")?
true:false);Params.debug=Params.settings.debug;try{Params.iFrame=
(window.top!=self)}catch(exception){new ErrorHandler(exception)}try{if(Params.mobile)
{Params.mobileId=getFromId("m_user_DEPRECATED").value}}catch(exception){new 
ErrorHandler(exception)}function trace(){if(!Params.dev)
{return}try{if(!traced[arguments.callee.caller.name]){traced[arguments.callee.caller.name]=0
```

Again, `Params.settings` seems to be undefined. This is a Facebook app, so I think this code may be relevant to Facebook.

Comment: Closure's base.js attempts to load deps.js for dynamic dependency loading in uncompiled code. Does your app load base.js separately from your compiled app JS code?

Comment: My app doesn't load base.js at all. It just loads the generated javascript.

Comment: Could you compile your code in WHITESPACE mode and post the code where the errors occur?